# How to use .notifyDataSetChanged() to update SimpleCursorAdapter in Listfragment?

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment, simplecursoradapter, notifydatasetchanged

I want to insert a new view data row to ListView(ListFragment), I already declare array in setAdapter() in method, but it has error with NullPointerException
how should I use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in new method?

I tried declare Cursor in new method again, or declare SimpleCursorAdapter in class, but they have some error

logCat:

```
03-21 02:41:30.099: W/dalvikvm(4130): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b60648)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130): java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at com.example.mycalc.NoteFragment.updateView(NoteFragment.java:80)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at com.example.mycalc.MainActivity.updateResult(MainActivity.java:34)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at com.example.mycalc.CalcFragment$1.onClick(CalcFragment.java:95)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-21 02:41:30.103: E/AndroidRuntime(4130):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NoteFragment:

```
package com.example.mycalc;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NoteFragment extends ListFragment {


private DB mDbHelper;
private Cursor mCursor;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
//String[] from_column = new String[]{DB.KEY_ITEM, DB.KEY_CREATED};
//int[] to_layout = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

//SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        //mCursor, from_column, to_layout);

private Cursor newCursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), layout, CalcFragment.InputResult);

    //setListAdapter(adapter);

    setAdapter();

    if(Debug.log){ Log.d("NoteFragment", "onCreated");}

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if( fm.findFragmentById(R.id.note_fragment)!= null){
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}

public void setAdapter(){

    mDbHelper= new DB(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();
    mCursor = mDbHelper.getAll();
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);

    String[] from_column = new String[]{DB.KEY_ITEM, DB.KEY_CREATED};
    int[] to_layout = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            mCursor, from_column, to_layout);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    if(Debug.log){ Log.d("NoteFragment", "setAdapter");}

}

public void updateView(){

    //mDbHelper= new DB(getActivity());
    //mDbHelper.open();
    //mCursor = mDbHelper.getAll();
    //getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);*/

    //String[] from_column = new String[]{DB.KEY_ITEM, DB.KEY_CREATED};
    //int[] to_layout = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    adapter.changeCursor(mCursor);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //if(Debug.log){ Log.d("NoteFragment", "updateView");}
}
```

}

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CalcFragment.OnEqualSelectedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void updateResult() {
        NoteFragment fragmentResult = new NoteFragment();
        fragmentResult.updateView();
        if(Debug.log){ Log.d("MainActivity", "updateResult");}
    }
```

New error msg:

```
03-22 13:49:07.321: W/dalvikvm(1566): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c21648)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.example.mycalc.NoteFragment.updateView(NoteFragment.java:80)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.example.mycalc.MainActivity.updateResult(MainActivity.java:34)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.example.mycalc.CalcFragment$1.onClick(CalcFragment.java:155)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-22 13:49:07.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you just add if(adapter != null) before using adapter?

Comment: hi Sushil. no I can't, it loaded sqlite datas when opened, and when I  initialize adapter and cursor again for `adapter.changeCursor(mCursor);` , it happened error with `mDbHelper.open();` or `mCursor = mDbHelper.getAll();`

Comment: @Sarah0050 You are calling `updateView()` before the system has a chance to call `onCreate()`. I suggest that you read about the Activity and Fragment lifecycles to understand how `onCreate()` is called.

Comment: I think `onCreate()` is happened only when app start first time, so I set adapter at here, the app runs OK at first `onCreate()` to `onResume()`, then until I click a btn from another fragment, to trigger the database and listview to update, is this process not right?

Comment: I know what you mean now, there's another mistake not about the databases, I declare a new fragment and call the method directly, so the context is nothing. I use Fragment Transaction to replace fragment, when fragment create just called setAdapter(),and it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        mCursor, from_column, to_layout);
```

This line declares a **local** variable. You don't initialize your member variable with the same name. You should change it to

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        mCursor, from_column, to_layout);
```

Comment: oops you posted first .you deserve +1

Comment: hi, Code-Guru, mcd.  I did it before, but it was the same error(sorry I mass it before post) I 'll modify it.

Comment: @Sarah0050 Please post your updated code and the new error message so that we can help.

Comment: @Code-Guru Thanks for help. I only changed the code `SimpleCursorAdapter adapter`back to `adapter`, now I update the new error msg at bottom(same error)

Answer (score 0):

actually you instantiate  adapter in local variable in setAdapter Method.

so change it to

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            mCursor, from_column, to_layout);
```